# Error in number sorting code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The following code should convert a string into an array of numbers and sort them in descending order. **The purpose is to find a substitution for the sort() method.**

Something is wrong. If 7 is placed in the first half of the array (like in the example), the code does not work properly. If you swap 7 for a number bigger than the last one (22 in the example), the code will work fine.

I'm looking to get it to work right regardless of the positioning of the numbers.

```
var row = '92 43 7 119 51 22';
var row = row.split(' ');
var column = row.map(Number);
function arrangeNum(column) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= column.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = column.length - i; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (column[j] > column[j - 1]) {
                var temp = column[j];
                column[j] = column[j - 1];
                column[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return column;
}

console.log(arrangeNum(column));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something is wrong. If 7 is placed in the first half of the array
>   (like in the example), the code does not work properly.

It is because of your *second-for-loop*'s initialization of `j`

Replace

```
for (var j = column.length - i; j >= 0; j--) {
```

with

```
for (var j = column.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
```

Notice that `j` is initialized to `column.length - 1`, but is only allowed to go as low as `i`

**Demo**

```js
function arrangeNum(column) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= column.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = column.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
      if (column[j] > column[j - 1]) {
        [column[j], column[j - 1]] = [column[j - 1], column[j]];
      }
    }
  }
  return column;
}

console.log( arrangeNum( '92 43 7 119 51 22'.split( /\s+/ ).map( Number ) ) );
```

Comment: This is what I needed to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you implemented the bubble sort wrong.

See this line `var j = column.length - i; j >= 0; j--`, will cause you to ignore the elements of the array starting from the right-side. Since this is a descending order algo, you need to ignore the elements from the left-side, so this: `var j = column.length - 1; j >= i; j--`.

I added some console logs to show this below:
[image]

See in yellow your algo ignores the first element on the next loop.

Below I added my full correction (you had some other minor issues):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= column.length; i++) {
        for (var j = column.length - i; j >= 0; j--) {
            console.log({i,j}, column.map((v,idx) => (idx===j) || (idx===j-1) ? `[${v}]` : v ).join(' '))
            if (column[j] > column[j - 1]) {
                var temp = column[j];
                column[j] = column[j - 1];
                column[j - 1] = temp;
                console.log({i,j}, '  ',column.map((v,idx) => (idx===j) || (idx===j-1) ? `[[${v}]]` : v ).join(' '))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just got the answer from another poster, it's the same issue as you mentioned. However, I will check the full edit for any other issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you just needed to reverse the order of execution of the `j` loop, starting from `0` till `column.length - 1`

```
var row = '92 43 7 119 51 22';
var row  = row.split(' ')
 var column = row.map(Number);
function arrangeNum(column) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= column.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= column.length - i; j++) { // SEE THIS
      console.log(column)
       if (column[j] > column[j - 1]) {
       var temp = column[j];
       column[j] = column[j - 1];
       column[j - 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}

return column;
}

console.log(arrangeNum(column))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls make change in a code as below.
It will work

```
 var row = '92 43 7 119 51 22';
 var row = row.split(' ');
 var column = row.map(Number);
 function arrangeNum(column) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= column.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = column.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {// see this change
        if (column[j] > column[j - 1]) {
          var temp = column[j];
          column[j] = column[j - 1];
          column[j - 1] = temp;
        }
     }
  }
   return column;
}

console.log(arrangeNum(column));
```

Comment: Yes, I got this answer by another user a few minutes ago. You can see it listed with the green check mark. Nevertheless, thank you for taking the time!